# Error when try to save the content of a file using ostream

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, fstream, cout, ostream

I wrote a program in C++ and compile this using gcc 7.3. This a simple program that writes   a  string in a file.
But a compiler error is generated only when compiles using the gcc 7.3. Using an old compiler 4.8.5 the program is succesfully compiled.

The compiler error is the following

> In member function 'void CDemoMap::saveFile(std::__cxx11::string&)':
>   ..\src\VerifyProgram.cpp:51:9: error: no match for 'operator<<'
>   (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}' and
>   'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}')
>       cout << print(coutFile)

Is anyone who can help me to solve this issue?
The code is the following

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream> 

#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
class CDemoMap
{
    public:
     map<int,int> m_sMap;
    void saveFile(std::string &);
    std::ostream& print(std::ostream  &s);
};


std::ostream& operator << (ostream& s, const CDemoMap &m)
{
   if (m.m_sMap.size())
   {
      s << "-----------------\nSOCKET FQDN MAP\n-----------------\n";
      s << "fqdn                    host:port              timestamp\n";

      for (map<int,int>::const_iterator iter = m.m_sMap.cbegin(); iter != 
           m.m_sMap.cend(); ++iter)
      {
         s << iter->first << "   " << (iter->second);
      }
      s << endl;
   }
   return s;
}
std::ostream& CDemoMap::print(std::ostream  &s)
{
   return s << (*this);
}

void CDemoMap::saveFile(std::string & test)
{
   char outFile[50];
   snprintf(outFile, sizeof(outFile), "Data:%s", test.c_str());

   std::ofstream coutFile;

   coutFile.open("Test.txt", std::ios::app);

   cout << print(coutFile);

   coutFile.close();
}


int main() {
    CDemoMap cSocket;
    string str = "Hello";
    cSocket.saveFile(str);
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems that the configuration of ostream& is expecting a file, when you are using the print option

Comment: Why this compiles in 4.8.5 compiler? 4.8.5 compiler does not support C++11 in comparison with 7.3.1. What has been changed in  ostream operator in latest standard ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under 4.8.5 the following line:

```
 cout << print(coutFile);
```

is translated into:

```
 void* v =  print(coutFile);
 std::cout << v;
```

because before C++11 there was operator converting ostream to `void*` to check if stream has no errors [from reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool):

> ```
> operator void*() const;
> (1)   (until C++11)
> explicit operator bool() const;
> (2)   (since C++11)
> Checks whether the stream has no errors.
> ```
>
> 1) Returns a null pointer if fail() returns true, otherwise returns a
>   non-null pointer. This pointer is implicitly convertible to bool and
>   may be used in boolean contexts.
>
> 2) Returns true if the stream has no
>   errors and is ready for I/O operations. Specifically, returns !fail().

Since C++11 the code cannot compile because conversion to void* is disabled.

Why do you want to pass return type of print - ostream to another ostream?
It just should be:

```
print(coutFile); // there is no need to pass ostream to cout
```